# Get DNS Servers in PHP

Tags: javascript, php

The command to retrieve data

```
<?php
//just to get keys
$data=file_get_contents('http://check2ip.com/');
$dataslip=explode("dns5",$data);
$prmkey=substr($dataslip[1],1,8);

//get DNS Servers of check2ip.com
$dnsservers=file_get_contents('http://check2ip.com/?prm='.$prmkey);

echo $dnsservers;
?>
```

It returned $prmkey, but does not return $dnsservers

How do I get the DNS servers!

Comment: I think the real question here is what are you trying to do?

Comment: @Dekel . I just want to get data from the page check2ip.com, is DNS Servers

Comment: Do you understand that it will not give you the same data as the one when you (as the user) view the page?

Comment: @Dekel Yes, I understand!
But with prm="key" right, I can get the DNS Servers {http://check2ip.com/?prm=}

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$result = dns_get_record('http://check2ip.com/?prm='.$prmkey);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Try that.